# django midleware inside function is not recognized it is giving me error 'function' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django-models, django-middleware, python-development-mode

error 'function' object has no attribute 'get' .inside dmy_middleware not recognized
here is code

```
def my_function(get_response):_
    print('hi')
    def dmy_middleware(request):
        response = get_response(request)
        print('go')
        return response
    return my_function
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are returning the middleware and not the function inside, this code works for me.

```
def my_function(get_response):_
    print('hi')
    def dmy_middleware(request):
        response = get_response(request)
        print('go')
        return response
    return dmy_middleware
```